# Google chrome also has a console object. Where is its equivalent API page?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, console

if I google 'firebug console API' it leads me to this page:

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API

which documents for me the Javascript console API I can use to write to the firebug console

Google chrome also has a console object.  Where is its equivalent API page?

For example, Firebug, allows: `console.log('%c%s', 'color: #ABC', 'hi')` to output a string in a particular color

While google chrome only accepts `console.log('%s', 'hi)` - it dosn't accept %c

Answer (score 8):

Chrome is using Webkit engine, same as Safari, so you can check out [Console API](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH8-SW20) from Safari.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a link to full documentation but you can at least glean all the methods available by running `console.log(console)`;